# Python nested loop error when inserting to DB

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, web-scraping

I have a code here that scrapes data from a specific website which is `https://vancouver.craigslist.org/search/ela`. My problem is when I execute my code, it gives me an error of `'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'` in the line `asdf = images.get_attribute("src")`. I am using selenium library in scraping the data. What I want is to insert the image url from my table which is named `images` but I cannot. What is wrong with my code?  I am not familiar with python yet thats why I am asking questions. Thanks a lot for consideration.

Current code

```
   x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hdrlnk')
    y = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]/span[@class="result-meta"]//span[@class="result-price"]')
    images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/a/img')
    for img in images:
      print(img.get_attribute('src'))
      for i in range(len(x)):
        asdf = images.get_attribute("src")
        prod = (x[i].text)
        price = (y[i].text)
        image = asdf
        sql =  """INSERT INTO products (name,price,image) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
        mycursor.execute(sql,(prod,price,image))
        mydb.commit()
```

When I comment this line

```
for img in images:
      print(img.get_attribute('src'))
```

and remove the `asdf` and `image` variable, I am able to insert the data and also when I comment this line of code and remain the print for images,

```
   #for i in range(len(x)):
        #asdf = images.get_attribute("src")
        #prod = (x[i].text)
        #price = (y[i].text)
        #image = asdf
        #sql =  """INSERT INTO products (name,price,image) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
        #mycursor.execute(sql,(prod,price,image))
        #mydb.commit()
```

I got the result I want which is like this

```
https://images.craigslist.org/00z0z_4cqgwC5PIXs_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00J0J_f6AnAonGjXd_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00606_mtKNjKREOO_300x300.jpg 
https://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_l5t0QnjZEPt_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00505_gIXt1C8aeqk_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00N0N_6P1GmSiL2vI_300x300.jpg
```

Sample data for `x` and `y` variable in `i` loop:

```
x = Spigen Magnetic Car Phone Mount
y= $20
```

What do I need to do in order to insert the image url with the product name and images in a single row? TIA.

EDIT. I tried @terahertz's answer and rewrite my code like this

```
  x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hdrlnk')
    y = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]/span[@class="result-meta"]//span[@class="result-price"]')
    images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/a/img')
    for img in images:
      # print(img.get_attribute('src'))
      for i in range(len(x)):
        asdf = img.get_attribute("src")
        prod = (x[i].text)
        price = (y[i].text)
        image = asdf
        sql =  """INSERT INTO products (name,price,image) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
        mycursor.execute(sql,(prod,price,image))
        mydb.commit()
```

Current DB datas

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | name                                                                   | price  | image                                                       |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1 | Spigen Magnetic Car Phone Mount                                        | $20    | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
|   2 | Netgear Nighthawk x6 r8000 wireless router                             | $120   | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
|   3 | iPod Touch 8gb 2nd generation - Loaded with Classic Rock               | $60    | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
|   4 | 3 plug 3.1A fast USB wallplugs                                         | $10    | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
|   5 | Audio and Video Cables                                                 | $3     | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
|   6 | Like New Samsung 50" HD TV ForSale                                     | $400   | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
|   7 | SONY Alarm Clock                                                       | $20    | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
|   8 | Bowers & Wilkins P7 Wireless MINT                                      | $450   | https://images.craigslist.org/00i0i_7PvHxDMvR2o_300x300.jpg |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I can insert into my database, BUT the problem is the `image` column has the same value with other. Its like only one image url inserted. And when I visited the link, the product name and the image doesnt match.

Answer (score 2):

Change `asdf = images.get_attribute("src")` to `asdf = img.get_attribute("src")`

Your outer loop is accessing each item in the `images` list with the variable `img`. But in your inner loop, you are accessing the `images` list.

Comment: It doesnt get me me the output that I want sir. What happened is I can insert into the database but, the image url is all the same for every products, and when I visited the link, the product name and the image dont match.

Comment: Hi Vince, would you be able to provide sample data of what `x` and `y` is? Without those, it will be very difficult to see if you had made a mistake with your loops. If it is not convenient to do so, then, please check if you really require nested loops to populate your data. In the nested (2nd for loop), the same image will be used to populate the other `prod` and `price` products in `x` and `y`.

Comment: When it comes to problems like this, I would suggest that you do a `print("prod", prod, "price", price, "image", image)` and check your console/terminal to see if you are populating the same row with the correct data. I suspect you don't need a nested for loop at all.

Comment: Its the same sir. The `name` and `price` is correct but the `image` url is always the same. It looks like this
`prod Epson Stylus CX5800F Colour Printer (ink included) & USB cable price $40 image https://images.craigslist.org/00e0e_f0raf0baSOw_300x300.jpg`

`prod HP Elitedisplay E222 22" 1080p Monitor price $50 image https://images.craigslist.org/00e0e_f0raf0baSOw_300x300.jpg`

`prod Samsung sound bar price $200 image https://images.craigslist.org/00e0e_f0raf0baSOw_300x300.jpg`

Comment: Have you removed this line `for i in range(len(x)):`? You are looping the same `img` again for the different product names and price.

Comment: I didint remove it sir. I will remove it and update you

Comment: if i will remove it sir what should i do with this code `prod = (x[i].text)
        price = (y[i].text)` ?

Comment: change `for img in images:` to `for i, image in enumerate(images):`

Comment: Now it has different image url, but there is another problem occured sir. The first product gets the 2nd image. Its like if i got `product_name[0]` the image got is `product_image[1]` It doesnt match

Comment: Check if `images` contain all the images you want starting from index 0. If image[0] is not the same as product_name[0], then you haven't crawled the data correctly and you won't be able to store them correctly.

Comment: The first result gets the second image sir when i `print(asdf)` Why is this happening?

Comment: because `images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li/a/img')` didn't crawl all the images.

Comment: Oh i see sir. What should I do with that?

Comment: Whats wrong with my xpath sir? I just copied the xpath of the image from my browser.

Comment: Sorry, I have never worked with xpath before, consider asking a separate question regarding that?